# How to set the _dont_enforce_csrf_checks using the django test client

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm trying to enforce the csrf checks during a higher level integration test using the django test client but I'm unsure how to flip this bit manually (before the client is invoked)

Here is what I have currently that is failing (I get a 201 instead of a 403 below)

```
def test_should_get_403_when_csrf_enforced(self):
    self.client.enforce_csrf_checks=False
    response = self.client.post(url, {'name': 'foobar'})
    self.assertEqual(403, response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this solution, first you must set the csrf token then you need to flip the enforce_csrf_check when you new up the client manually

```
def test_should_get_403_when_csrf_enforced(self):
    self.client = test.Client(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    self.client.cookies[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME] = 'asdf'                                                  
    response = self.client.post(url, {'name': 'foobar'})
    self.assertEqual(403, response.status_code)
```